# Python - insert json file into elasticsearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have this Json in a file:

```
{
   "name": "Huntington Beach",
   "beach": "50 N of Santa Ana River",
   "SampleDate": "02/01/18",
   "ParameterCode": "Enterococcus",
   "Qualifier": "=",
   "Result": "8",
   "Units": "CFU/100ml"
 },
```

I wrote this script which should print all of the json text:

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import urllib
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
from elasticsearch.serializer import JSONSerializer
import os,sys

directory = '/home/Documents/folder/myfile.json'

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': '', 'port': }])

with open(directory, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data=json.loads(f.read())
pprint(data)

es.index(index='my_index', doc_type='doc', body=data)
```

It doesn't work, can you help me? This is what happens:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:

Comment: You have a trailing comma in your JSON, it's not valid.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @dwjv, your json file is not valid:

```
{
   "name": "Huntington Beach",
   "beach": "50 N of Santa Ana River",
   "SampleDate": "02/01/18",
   "ParameterCode": "Enterococcus",
   "Qualifier": "=",
   "Result": "8",
   "Units": "CFU/100ml"
 }, <---trailing comma
```

Just remove it and you should be good to go.